# ng build and ng serve (are they properly used in my Dockerfile?)

Tags: angular, docker, npm, dockerfile

So, I've taken over a rather big angular project a while ago, and I still haven't fully grapsed all of it. I develop locally. When I have a new version ready, I push the repo to Gitlab and there, it is automatically deployed inside a Docker container that runs in a kubernetes network.

When I test locally, I use `ng serve`, which works nicely, because I can see live changes.

I've had a look at some of the project files and wonder if they make sense:

The `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# build app
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build:prod

# serve app
CMD npm start
```

In `package.json`, there are the following scripts:

```
"start": "ng serve",
"build:prod": "ng build --output-hashing none --configuration production && node build-elements.js",
```

So, that means when the docker container is set up, it first runs `ng build`, then `node build-elements.js`and then `ng serve`, doesn't it? I thought, `ng serve` was more for the development environment?

In `angular.json`, there is this entry under `"architects"`:

```
"serve": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
   "options": {
      "browserTarget": "simplecomp:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
   },
   "configurations": {
      "production": {
         "browserTarget": "simplecomp:build:production"
      }
   }
 },
```

This defines what is done when `ng serve` is called, am I right?

Does all of that make sense? I have the feeling that calling `ng serve` in the Dockerfile isn't the right way to do it. What would be better?

Thx

Comment: Can somebody explain to me why I'm not getting answers? Is my question unclear? I thought it was not so hard to answer for someone who knows angular/npm better than me. Thx

Comment: Have you found it? I'm getting the same issue